# Embedding YouTube Playlist using SWFObject.embedSWF()

Tags: javascript, youtube, embed, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to use YouTube's JavaScript API to embed a playlist to my Facebook app.

I tried using the standard code as shown by Google [***here***](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=youtube#simple_embed) to embed a simple video and it worked.

The code is:

```
    function loadPlayer() {
        // The video to load
        var videoID = "[My Video ID]";
        // Lets Flash from another domain call JavaScript
        var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
        // The element id of the Flash embed
        var atts = { id: "ytPlayer" };
        // All of the magic handled by SWFObject (http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)
        swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + videoID + 
                           "?fs=1&version=3&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=player1", 
                           "videoDiv", "420", "315", "9", null, null, params, atts);
      }
```

But how do I use the YouTube API to **embed a Playlist**?

I'm aware of the **playlist parameter** on the embedSWF URL parameter, but what it does is **append** videos as to make a playlist on the fly.

I already have a playlist on my YouTube account, now I want to embed it using the API.

How can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on something similar and in looking for the solution to my problem may have found yours...

In the place where you have;

```
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + videoID +
```

Change that to:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/p/" + playlistID +
```

I do believe that will work.  That's what puts our playlist on the player.  And yet, it is not the way we are hoping to display it.  We would like a list below the player, so I am still searching for that answer.

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

You dont need javascript or anything, you just go into your playlist, and next to the play all button it says share, click that then click embed and copy and past the code on your site.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you to try on your own... http://jsfiddle.net/masiha/tFQEN/1/